# How to force user to input at least a character or certain characters that cannot be bypassed in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am creating a program where the user must guess the random number between 1-20. But, the user must type their name first (or at least a character). I can't seem to force the user to type something. How do I force the user to type something? Here's my source code:
https://gist.github.com/AmmarFMR/dca16caf88c4c0b2d1b10a97becf3592

I also faced the problem at the end when a question is prompted to the user, "Do you want to play again? (Y/N)". The user could bypass the choices by either pressing enter twice or characters other than Y/N twice. How do I fix this?

And, I am sure that my simple program could be written in a more effective or shorter way. Please feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: Note that a [mcve] must be **in the question**, but probably you want something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: You don't; you take what the user chooses to enter, and decide whether to ask for a different, more acceptable response.

Comment: Put the `input` in a `while` loop and keep looping until you get valid data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
nothing = True 
while nothing == True:
    print('What is your name?')
    name = input()
    if name != "":
        nothing = False
```

You can put all your code in a while loop and do the same thing or you can use break in the if statement to break the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about the while loop. This solution also works for the second problem that I faced.